# How to determine a functions` return value choosing possible options at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two virtually identical function that receive same struct as parameter.
A very simplified version of my functions like below:

```
struct Container {
 int A;
 int B;
}

int return_A_dependent(Container c){
  //... identical code for A and B ...
  int common_for_A_and_B = 0;
  return common_for_A_and_B + c.A;
}

int return_B_dependent(Container c){
  // ... identical code for A and B ...
  int common_for_A_and_B = 0;
  return common_for_A_and_B + c.B;
}
```

only difference between two functions is their return values that are depend on the structs' different variables.
I want to combine these two functions without doing runtime check. Like passing a flag parameter and add a if statement to forward the return value like below:

```
int return_A_or_B(Container c, bool flag_A) {
 // ... identical code for A and B ...
  int common_for_A_and_B = 0;
  if (flag_A) {
    return common_for_A_and_B + c.A;
  }
  else {
    return common_for_A_and_B + c.B;
  }
```

How could I handle this at compile time without using "if"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `bool` template parameter and an `if constexpr` should do the job.

Comment: Pass directly `c.a`/`c.b` instead of the `bool` ?

Comment: @Quentin have Cpp-11only

Comment: @zontragon please remember to tag appropriately then :)

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, you are right.

Comment: Is it really worth it? Can't you just put the common part into a separate function?

Comment: @Jarod42 Passing c.a and c.b separately needs some boilerplate code.If I couldn't find a better solution I'll do like you said.

Comment: @zontragon are flag_A, c.A/Bm and etc. all compile-time constants? If they are, why not just slap constexpr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

template using pointer to member as a parameter (or just normal function with extra argument):

```
template<int Container::* p_member> int
Work(Container c)
{
    int common_for_A_and_B = 0;
    return common_for_A_and_B + c.*p_member;
}

Work<&Container::A>(c);
```